# How to avoid kickout from SSH when script fail

Tags: shell-script, shell-builtin

Please forgive my basic unix/linux scripting skill and poor English

I am testing a script in the Linux VM, let's say it is `work.sh`. So I have to ssh to the VM

```
ssh myname@theVm.domain.app
```

with my access, then I need to run the script in my home folder

```
[myname@theVm.domain.app ~]. work.sh param1 param2
```

When something goes wrong in the batch script, I can see the error but also get kicked out of the VM/ssh session

```
Connection to myname@theVm.domain.app closed.
```

so I have to log back in.

I tried nohup, but I also like to have any error/log output to the console. What is the better way to handle this situation

Comment: Why are you sourcing the script (with `.`) instead of running it (`./work.sh`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with my access, then I need to run the script in my home folder
> `[myname@theVm.domain.app ~]. work.sh param1 param2`

There are two ways to invoke an script : the "normal call" and the "dot call" or "sourcing":

> `$ /path/to/executable`
> `$ . /path/to/executable`

The difference is: The first variant will make the OS start a new process (a child process of your shell), load and execute the script there and when the so loaded script ends its run the process is closed again - and you are back in your shell process, which will in all likelyhood present you another prompt.

The second variant acts similar, but with a vital difference: there is no child process created but the script is loaded and executed in the *current process*. I am not sure what `work.sh` does (if you want a comment on that you should have posted its contents), but my suspicion is it leaves your login shell somehow and this is what causes the disconnect. Don't start it with a dot in front and you most probably won't experience the disconnects again.

**BONUS Information**
In my experience beginners learn best and fastest when they can be shown some experiment to see the effect of something. So here it is:

You can see the difference between dot-execution and normal execution by writing the following script and saving it as "my_script.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
my_x="abc"
my_y="def"
```

Don't forget to make it executable (`chmod 754 my_script.sh`) and execute the script the normal way, then display the content of the two defined variables:

```
$ ./my_script.sh
$ echo $my_x $my_y
```

The effect you will see is: nothing - the variables are not set. The reason is simple: at the start of the script another process was started, the definition of the variables happened *there* and they vanished again when the process was closed because they were part of *that* environment, not yours.

Now run the same script with dot-execution:

```
$ . ./my_script.sh
$ echo $my_x $my_y
abc def
```

You will notice that this time the variables are indeed set: the reason is that the script was not executed in some new process but in yours - hence the variable definition took place in your environment and subsequently are still there.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like there is a `set -e` in the script.  Closing the shell would be expected behaviour if a sourced script (run with `. scriptname`) throws an error with that setting enabled.

Without any insight into the script, I can't say for sure that you shouldn't be running it with `.`  but it's an unusual way to do things.

I would try running it with:

```
./work.sh param1 param2
```

If you are trying to get past a missing execute bit preventing you from running the script, you could try:

```
$SHELL ./work.sh param1 param2
```

Alternatively you could start an additional shell and run as you are at present -- this might let you see an error message

```
$SHELL
. work.sh param1 param2
```